# How to call a function if Invokable funtion does not exist?

Tags: c#

```
_helperClass?.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3);

if(_helperClass == null) // .... or any type of check
{
DoOthers();
}
```

I want to call a function or fire an event if _helperClass is null or not defined. I leave an example to explain what I want to do.

```
_helperClass?.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3) : DoOthers();
```

Is it possible to do this, or what is the best practice?

?: ->   These operators can't be overloaded in C#.

Comment: HelperClass may or may not be assigned in the project, if it is assigned I am using the first part. In both cases, the flow is expected to be completed. If this class is defined or assigned, DoSomething() will run, otherwise DoOthers() will run. I could do an if block here, but I'd like to convert it to a ternary style as it will be used in so many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you performing a standalone statement or evaluating an expression?  That makes a difference in how you might structure it.  Keeping in mind that the null conditional operator *is not* a drop-in replacement for an `if/else` structure.

---

If you're just performing a statement then semantically you already have exactly what you want.  Define the semantics as:

> If _helperClass is null, do one thing.  Else, do another.

Which makes the code clear and simple:

```
if(_helperClass == null)
{
    DoOthers();
}
else
{
    _helperClass.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

Or, if you prefer the opposite semantics, you can invert the condition:

```
if(_helperClass != null)
{
    _helperClass.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3);
}
else
{
    DoOthers();
}
```

---

*Alternatively*, if what you have is *an expression* (that is, if the result of one or the other of these method calls should be used in-line by surrounding code), then you can make use of the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).  For example:

```
_helperClass == null ? DoOthers() : _helperClass.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3)
```

Or, inverting the semantics of the condition:

```
_helperClass != null ? _helperClass.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3) : DoOthers()
```

It *looks like* you were trying to do exactly that in your second code sample, but you weren't making use of the `?` part of the conditional operator or using any kind of condition.  It appears you were confusing it with the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators) used for member access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the most readable way to solve this situation is to check with an if block. Because I'm not sure the 2nd example you gave will work.

_helperClass == null ? DoOthers() : _helperClass.DoSomething(param1, param2, param3)

Having a logic structure on the left side of the "?" sign causes an error.